# Excel countIf + concatenate function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel formula that does a simple count if. However, I want to add a condition to that, if met would change the fill colour of the cell.
Example:
In Sheet 1 cell A1 I have "XXX". In Sheet 1 cell A2 I have a boolean of "True". In Sheet 2 cell B1, I have

```
    =COUNTIF(A1,"*XXX*")
```

What I want to do is say that if in Sheet 1 cell A1 I have XXX AND Sheet 1 Cell A2 is "True" then in Sheet 2 cell B1 I should have "1" displayed within a red cell

An alternate to the color coding would be to say that if Sheet 1 cell A2 has a boolean of "True" and Sheet 1 cell A1 has XXX then on sheet 2 cell B1, I should have "1R" displayed.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with VBA, this code will do what you want:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name of your sheet
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Change the name of your sheet

Lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To Lastrow Step 2

    If ws1.Cells(i, "A") = "SEC" And ws1.Cells(i + 1, "A") = True Then
        ws2.Cells(i, "B") = 1
        ws2.Cells(i, "B").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
'       ws2.Cells(i, "B") = "1R" ' Alternate to the color coding
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Code based on commnents below

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long, c As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name of your sheet
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Change the name of your sheet

i = 3
    For c = 7 To 25


        If ws2.Cells(i, "K") > 0 And ws2.Cells(i, "L") = False Then
            ws1.Cells(3, c).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

        ElseIf ws2.Cells(i, "K") > 0 And ws2.Cells(i, "L") = True Then
            ws1.Cells(3, c).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
i = i + 2

Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: @FatOwl i am not sure to understand well. What do you mean by "map the corresponding rows"? Meaning that `Sheets(1).Range("G3:Y12")` will be the same as `Sheets(2).Range("G3:Y12")`? And on which sheet you want to change the color, Sheet(1) or still Sheet(2)?

Comment: @FatOwl let me know if it is what you are loking

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use *Conditional formatting*, which you will find at *Start>Styles*.

1. Select the cell that you need the colour to change
2. Add a new Rule
3. Make it formula dependant
4. Use the formula `=(Sheet1!A2=TRUE)`
5. Format the sample cell below to match your requirements
6. Add a new rule for each color you want (in case you prefered green for FALSE items, for example)

Comment: Once you have the rule set, it works like any other formula in that cell. You can drag  it down if you wish. Just make sure that you don't fix the reference (clicking cells from the rule editor will automatically add `$` markers to the cell reference). The VBA code suggested by @manu it's also an option, but then you have to use .xlsm filetypes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could say:`=if(and(a1="sec",a2="true"),1,"False Text")`
This will only return 1, or you could amend to "1R", if both a1 and A2 return the test you put into the and statement.